# How to update an Entity after SaveChanges to obtain a backend sequence assignment?

Tags: database, entity-framework, postgresql

I can't get this to work. I have an EntityFramework 6 with PostgreSQL backend.

The PostgreSQL (9.5) backend uses a trigger of getnextticketnumber to sequentially assign integers to new records as they are added. After the EntityFramework creates a new record in the database with SaveChanges(), the record id on the new entity is correctly updated. However, the ticketno of the entity remains null despite that fact that checking the corresponding record in the database does have a non-null ticket number assigned. So it would appear that the PostgreSQL record is being correctly made, but the entity will continue to show it as null. That is, this gives the wrong results:

```
 // read back ticket to get the ticketno from Postgresql.
   ticket = ctx.established_patients.Where(t => t.recid == ticket.recid).First();
```

Here is the supporting documentation. 
TIA for any idea on why this is not working and/or how to make it work!

```
established_patients ticket = (from e in ctx.established_patients
                         where e.patient_recid == estpt.recid
                         select e)
                         .SingleOrDefault();

                if (ticket == null)
                {
                    // create a ticket for an established patient
                    ticket = new established_patients
                    {
                        modified = DateTime.Now,
                        patient_recid = estpt.recid,
                        ticketno = null
                    };
                    ctx.established_patients.Add(ticket);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    // read back ticket to get the ticketno from Postgresql.
                    ticket = ctx.established_patients.Where(t => t.recid == ticket.recid).First();
                }
                ticketno = (int)ticket.ticketno;
                return ticketno;
```

The PostgreSQL (9.5) trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextticketnumber()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- Check for null ticketnumber
  IF NEW.ticketno is null THEN
    New.ticketno := nextval('patient_ticket_number_seq');
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION getnextticketnumber()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The trigger is placed on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE established_patients
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  ticketno integer,
  patient_recid integer NOT NULL,
  modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT established_patients_pk PRIMARY KEY (recid),
  CONSTRAINT established_patients_patient_fk FOREIGN KEY (patient_recid)
      REFERENCES patients (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT established_patients_unqiue UNIQUE (patient_recid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE established_patients
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Trigger: new_ticket_number on established_patients

-- DROP TRIGGER new_ticket_number ON established_patients;

CREATE TRIGGER new_ticket_number
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON established_patients
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE getnextticketnumber();

-- Trigger: update_modified on established_patients

-- DROP TRIGGER update_modified ON established_patients;

CREATE TRIGGER update_modified
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON established_patients
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();
```

Comment: Is ticketno an auto increment field? Why do you need a trigger for that?

Comment: @jpgrassi  I have several tables that each describe different sets of data. Each of these tables are then related back to a single table. The ticketno needs to be unique to the database, not just to the table. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not map the entity properly. If you need that the DBMS handles it (and EF reads it) you need to mark it as StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed.
If you don't you could also have the problem that EF try to write it during updates.

For more info
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296755(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the tip. I also found this to work: ctx.Entry(ticket).Reload();  but it seemed like an unnecessary extra step.